# WooCommerce prices location in DB

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm looking for the location of a product's prices according to the option which the user selects in the product price. For example, [this WooCommerce shop](http://sakala.ir/product/bundle-cashmere-3) has a select which prices change according to the user selection.

I want to know where are prices for different options stored in DB.

Thanks

Comment: A product is a **custom post** which **post_type** is **"product"**. In database you have to look in **posts** table which `post_type` is `product`. For each `post_id`  *(product id)* you can find all related data to this product in **postmeta** table: `SELECT *  FROM 'postmeta' WHERE 'post_id' = nnnn` *(nnnn is the number ID of one product)*. All the different prices for each product are store in "postmeta" table.

Answer (score 13):

All the data like different **prices** of a product custom post type are store *(for each product)* in **postmeta table**.

To find the **post id** of all products you have to use this query on **posts table**:

```
SELECT *  FROM 'posts' WHERE 'post_type' = 'product'
```

For each **product id** (`post_id`), you can retrieve all related data with this query on **postmeta table**:

```
SELECT * FROM 'postmeta' WHERE 'post_id' = nnnn
```

*(nnnn is the number id (`post_id`) of a product)*
You will get the list of all product properties `metakey` and `metavalues`. 
For related price `meta_key`(s) you have, for example:
- `_regular_price`
- `_sale_price`
- `_price`
- …

To get a particular value of a product meta_key, you can use the wordpress function:

`get_post_meta($post_id, '$meta_key');`

Comment: In Woocommerce, what is the difference between `_regular_price` and `_price`?

Comment: @ptrcao "_price" is the active price (that can be the regular price or the sale price if defined). "_regular_price" is the price that you enter in your product, under regular price.

Comment: Thanks - and where/how does one define the "active" price?

Comment: @ptrcao If the product is on sale (with a defined and active sale price), the active price "_price" is equal to  the sale price (so different than the regular price). If the product is not on sale the active price "_price" is equal to the regular price.

Answer (score 4):

As LoicTheAztec told, the product data lives in the posts and postmeta tables. Here is a query, I used to get the prices in my environment (WC Role Based Price installed)

```
SELECT
  wpp.ID,
  wppm.meta_key AS FIELD,
  wppm.meta_value AS VALUE,
  wppm.*
FROM wp_posts AS wpp
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wppm
    ON wpp.ID = wppm.post_id
WHERE wpp.post_type = 'product'
      AND (wppm.meta_key = '_regular_price'
      OR wppm.meta_key = '_sale_price'
      OR wppm.meta_key = '_price'    
      OR wppm.meta_key = '_product_attributes')
ORDER BY wpp.ID ASC, FIELD ASC, wppm.meta_id DESC;
```

Perhaps this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Ηere are three meta_keys in **postmeta** table.

```
[ _sale_price, _regular_price, _price ]
```

First array contains value and second array contains WHERE condition. You can add more conditions.

You can update values using the following code.

```
//update _price
$wpdb->update( 
    $wpdb->postmeta, 
    array( 'meta_value' => $default_product_price ), 
    array( 'meta_key' => '_price' )
);
//update _regular_price
$wpdb->update( 
    $wpdb->postmeta, 
    array( 'meta_value' => $default_product_price ), 
    array( 'meta_key' => '_regular_price' )
);
//update _price
$wpdb->update( 
    $wpdb->postmeta, 
    array( 'meta_value' => $default_sale_price ), 
    array( 'meta_key' => '_sale_price' )
);
```

Comment: Queries are incomplete. It is essential to set in the second array (WHERE clause) the **post_id** otherwise the same price will be set to all posts (we assume products).

Answer (score 0):

This prints product title and it's price.

```
 SELECT distinct p.id, p.post_title,pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value 
 FROM {db_prefix}_postmeta pm 
inner join {db_prefix}_posts p on p.id= pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_sale_price'
```